# Child Process Exec Failed Electron App Calling nodejs SpeedTest

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, command, speed-test

I tried to execute a nodejs command inside electron.

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('node', ['--version'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

That one above is fine! And give an output nicely.
But then once i execute :

```
npm install --global --save speed-test
```

under one of **my Electron App**.

And try to execute a different command such as:

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const child = execFile('speed-test', null, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

it gaves me an error:

```
Uncaught Error: spawn speed-test ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80)
```

The more interesting part is that, If i execute the command itself under CommandPrompt of Nodejs, it's perfect! So... i'm confused.

[image: preview]

What the things that i need to modify under the Electron App anyway?

Comment: `const s = execFileSync('speed-test', { encoding: 'utf8' });`

Comment: Try to use this one

Comment: and to check the result `console.log(s)`